# How to change the looks or improve the looks of the VB.NET application?

Tags: .net, vb.net

We are very much bored with use of very powerful but very dirty looks of VB.Net Controls.
We made application in VB.NET 2005. 
Now we want to change the look and filed of the application.
we had tried to change with by changing colors and font but it still looks like very dirty.
So how we change that, I had heard about **WPF** but never had used it.
what you recommended me to change the look and field of the application.

Dirty means, very old style. [ for me ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) will be a good way to go.

The key question is "How hard will this be?"

The answer depends on how well presentation and functionality are separated in your application. If the two are conflated together, you're looking pretty much at a rewrite. But, if you have good separation between the two, or if you're willing to put in the work to achieve this separation, you'll be able to migrate.

You needn't migrate the entire application in one go - though you might want to hold off on most theming changes until you have.

Comment: WPF is awesome. To get a basic understanding read some Expression Blend tutorials.

Comment: Yes...i also at last go with WPF.

Answer (score 0):

use `Application.EnableVisualStyles` on the mainform load event, or as the first command of Main

Comment: It is a check box in the VB.NET IDE, turned on by default.  Project + Properties, Application tab, Enable XP Visual Styles.